# Web API: Should the body of my POST method contains the identifier?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What is the common rule or best practices about creating (POST method) a new item in my database with a Web API (REST). Should the body of my POST method contains the identifier?

With identifier:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(AddressModel addressModel)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
            if (context.address.Any(y => y.id == addressModel.id)
                throw new Exception("Item already exist"); // or return BadRequest
            ...
    }
}
```

Without identifier:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(AddressModel addressModel)
{
    if (addressModel.id != null)
        throw new Exception("identifier cannot be set"); // or return BadRequest

    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
            addressModel.id = GetNewId();
            // GetNewId generate the next correct if from data 
            // from context.address.last ...
            ...
    }
}
```

*And of course (before downvoting) you can just tell me there is no correct answer because the first solution is more efficient in this or this case and the other one is better for other reason. Of course I have my own opinion and this is an opinion question for people without experience like me. But for people with experience I'm sure they can answer this question without hesitation and with non opinionated arguments. So this is not en opinionated question or please tell me why.*

Comment: How does the consumer of your API know what the Id should be? Are you telling or asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating an object, the API should be responsible for assigning the unique id. Otherwise, the caller has to know too much about how the API works (what type of id, how do we get unique values, etc.).

Also, you can return the assigned if if the caller needs it for later operations.